# Can valgrind be used along with Cygwin?

Tags: c, cygwin, valgrind

I am building source on Windows using Cygwin, I need to find places with memory leaks and possible memory leaks. I know about Valgrind used for memory leak detection in Linux.

- Can Valgrind be used along with Cygwin so that it works in a Windows based environment?
- If yes can you please tell what configurations, etc. are needed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No it's **not** [supported](http://www.valgrind.org/info/platforms.html).

Also, an obvious link: http://www.google.com/search?q=cygwin+valgrind

Comment: The top search result from that query is now this question :)

Comment: Maybe it was, not anymore.

Comment: Maybe it was, not anymore.